# Order of bean creation and call to auto-configuration class in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, shared-libraries, javabeans, spring-autoconfiguration

I am creating a spring boot library with auto-configuration. The library reads the message from given kafka topic and processes it.

The library has a configuration class:

```
public class LibConfiguration{
    public String topicName;
}
```

The application using this library is supposed to create bean of this class. The library will use the `topicName` to read from it as soon as the application starts.

I was wondering about the order in which the library's auto configuration class is called and the bean is created.

Is it guaranteed that the bean will be created first?

Comment: It is guaranteed. If this bean is auto-wired somewhere in the library's configuration class and it does NOT exist then application won't start at all.